# How to disable CAPTCHA for QA env in firebase auth (react native app)?

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, automation, captcha

We are working on the test automation framework for react-native app.
When we try to log in on the app on iOS build (manually or automatically) we get redirected to the captcha :
[image]

How we can to disable captcha for firebase auth?
Why the captcha appears only on iOS build?

Update:
It is possible to do this without firebase.auth().signInAnonymously() mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185024/how-to-remove-captcha-verification-from-firebase-phone-auth-using-javascript) ?

Answer (score 1):

You should enable silent notification

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth#start-receiving-silent-notifications

Comment: Masoud could you point them directly to the part of the document that will help them disable Captcha when going through Firebase auth. This will help them find the answer quicker.

Comment: Hello welcome to so. I think you miss interpreted the question.

Comment: @kelvin reCAPTCHA is used automatically if silent push notifications aren't enabled or aren't possible on a particular device, e.g. a simulator.

LandonCall
https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1171