# How to implement firebase phone verification system without using captcha verifier?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, recaptcha

I have implemented firebase default phone authentication that uses captcha verifier which is required by google, it is working but captcha is giving error "Recaptcha verification failed - DUPE". I want to get rid of the error and captcha verifier.

```
           firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
           // Create a Recaptcha verifier instance globally
            // Calls submitPhoneNumberAuth() when the captcha is verified
            window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(
            "recaptcha-container_new",
             {
               size: "normal",
               callback: function(response) {
               submitPhoneNumberAuth();
             }
           }
       );

           function submitPhoneNumberAuth() {
             var phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value;
             var appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
             firebase
             .auth()
             .signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
             .then(function(result) {
              confirmationResult = result;
               console.log(result);
             })
               .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
              });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

**size must be invisible**

```
firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container_new', {
  'size': 'invisible'
});
```

[Angular 7 & Firebase Login with Phone Number (use invisible reCAPTCHA) in Turkish Language](https://medium.com/@toprakerzurumluoglu/angular-7-firebase-login-with-phone-number-use-invisible-recaptcha-dda07494736b)

I hope its useful.

Comment: Yes I did that  earlier, actually the problem is this error "Recaptcha verification failed - DUPE". It generates the error in both modes 'normal' or 'invisible'. If there is a way to completely remove captcha verification?

Comment: Did you use "recaptcha-container_new" in .html file? Such as `<div id="recaptcha-container_new"></div>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185024/how-to-remove-captcha-verification-from-firebase-phone-auth-using-javascript any helpful things available in this?

Comment: @KamranAli I'm not robot like Firebase UI can't be added using normal fb sdk? https://fir-ui-demo-84a6c.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: I did that as my shared on medium. [medium post](https://medium.com/@toprakerzurumluoglu/angular-7-firebase-login-with-phone-number-use-invisible-recaptcha-dda07494736b) - [PhoneLogin](https://envatotoprak.firebaseapp.com/home/phone)

Comment: Yes could be used but according to google docs they required their own recaptcha verifier

Comment: Actually I am using firebase for phone number verification

Comment: @KamranAli How You solved This Problem. Please share?